# Read Sound Profile in Android using Broadcastreceiver with Blank Activity in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I like to read the Sound Profile whenever the user changes it and display a Toast.
For this I used a Blank Activity and added only broadcastreceiver to my App (I don't want the user to see the app in the App drawer).

Following receiver was added in the intent filter of manifest file

```
<action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" />
```

But I am not able to receive the broadcast.

Thank you.

Edit: Adding code of my broadcastreceiver

```
public class SoundProfileChanger extends BroadcastReceiver {


public SoundProfileChanger() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int PresentAudioMode = audioManager.getRingerMode();

    if (PresentAudioMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Ringer Mode Normal",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (PresentAudioMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Ringer Mode Silent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Ringer Mode Vibrate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code as well and also you have an activity right?

Comment: I am using Android Studio. I chose blank activity and added a BroadcastReceiver class.

Comment: To clear things up, I don't have much knowledge about the specific Audio Manager (Never use it much). But I am quite good with Broadcast Receivers. For starters since I don't have the full Manifest file, add this just below `onReceive`. `Log.e("TAG", "onReceive is called");`. Or if your more comfortable with `Toast` statements add `Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive is called", Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();` This helps clear up if there is a problem in the Broadcast Receiver class you have created or the way in which you have declared it. Try this out first and let me know. BTW Where is ur import